# Understanding BELLMAN-FORD algorithm from CLRS

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford, clrs

Consider this simple graph:

`S -> A -> B -> C`

In CLRS, the authors have implemented a loop which goes for |V|-1.
But according to `path-relaxation property` a simple path `P` can be < s,a,b,c >.

Using the `path-relaxation property` we are going to relax the edges of `P` in the following order

`(S,A),(A,B),(B,C)`

So, we will be done in a single pass for our `|V| - 1` iterations. I can understand the use of `|V| -1` passes, had the `path-relaxation property` not specified that we relax the path, starting from 'the source'.

What's the point of |V| - 1 iterations here? Where am I going wrong, with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the any shortest path between any two nodes can't contain greater than `|V|` nodes or `|V|-1` edges. By relaxing the edges for `|V|-1` times we are sure that we have got the optimal distance between two nodes ( if there at all exists a optimal path).